# Arquillian and Flyway using different versions of H2 in-memory

Tags: java, h2, flyway, jboss-arquillian, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm trying to create a JPA-helper, which will eventually be turned into a jar and used in other projects. I want to add Integration tests to this project, so I've added a `TestEntity` and `TestService` class (these refer to a simple `TEST` table in the `DB` schema).

The goal is to create an in-memory database with [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), run the test in a container with [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/), and create/populate a test database with [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). Flyway is triggered by having a listener for an `@ApplicationScoped` class.

However, whenever I trigger an integration test, the test seems to work correctly until a `count(*)` query is called. At this point, Hibernate complains that the schema (that was just created in Flyway) doesn't exist: `Schema 'DB' does not exist`

There are a lot of logs, but the highlights look like this:

- A test Glassfish server is started
- Hibernate starts

  - it does not complain about anything yet
  - if `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `validate`, then it complains that the tables created in Flyway do not exist (`Schema-validation: missing table [DB.TEST]`)
- Flyway executes the data migration

  - it says that both scripts execute successfully
- The Test code starts running
- The code fails

  - `Schema 'DB' does not exist`

### What I think I need to do

I think that Flyway and the EntityManager are talking to different instances of the database. The changes that Flyway makes aren't saved in a way that EntityManager can see them.

- Ensure that the `EntityManager` and `Flyway` are talking to the same database.

  - The name is identical (see `persistence.xml`, `EntityManagerFactory`, and `FlywayDataLoader`), and I've tried adding/removing various `MODE` values with no effect.
- Force the Flyway code to execute before the Hibernate code
- Force Hibernate to refresh it's schema before the testing starts

### What I've tried

- Putting a syntax error into the Flyway migration code causes the test to fail due to a SQL error.

  - The same happens if you put a duplicate statement into the SQL code (e.g.: create the table or schema a second time).
- I tried triggering Flyway via a startup script in the JDBC connection string

  - i.e.: `jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create.sql'`
  - I know that the script triggered (because adding errors causes the test to fail), but it still doesn't solve the `Schema 'DB' does not exist` problem.
- Various flavors of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

  - `none` : `Schema 'DB' does not exist`
  - `validate` : `Schema-validation: missing table [DB.TEST]`
  - `update`, `create-drop` : the tables are created, but the data from Flyway is missing
- Put the Flyway code within `EntityManagerFactory.create()`
- Put the Flyway code in an [Integrator class](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-envers/src/main/java/org/hibernate/envers/boot/internal/EnversIntegrator.java) and [reference](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-envers/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator)
- Change the Flyway/persistence.xml connection to use a file for the DB rather than memory (e.g.: `jdbc:h2:~/test-db`).

  - This creates a file in `C:\Users\<me>` named `test-db.mv`. The file shows evidence of Flyway interacting with it, but the EntityManager still generates the `Schema 'DB' does not exist` error.
  - I also set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create`, then searched my entire hard drive for a second instance of `test-db.mv`, but could not find one.

### What won't work

- [Arquillian Persistence](http://arquillian.org/arquillian-extension-persistence/)

  - It looks awesome, but I'm on a company network and they haven't approved it yet
- Spring-*

  - This project doesn't use Spring anything

### Logs and Code

#### Execution Logs

```
// various "server startup" logs
// ...
// misc hibernate logs
Apr 15, 2020 9:40:39 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: TestDS
    ...]
// ...
Loading Flyway Data
8 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.VersionPrinter - Flyway Community Edition 5.0.7 by Boxfuse
246 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory - Database: jdbc:h2:mem:test (H2 1.4)
354 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.028s)
377 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory - Creating Schema History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history"
413 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
415 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - CreateDatabase
436 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - AddTestClasses
449 [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.078s)
Apr 15, 2020 9:40:44 AM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start
INFO: Loading application [test] at [/test]
Apr 15, 2020 9:40:45 AM org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand execute
INFO: test was successfully deployed in 7,649 milliseconds.
Apr 15, 2020 9:40:45 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(testobject0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        DB.TEST testobject0_ 
    where
        1=1
Apr 15, 2020 9:40:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 30000, SQLState: 42Y07
Apr 15, 2020 9:40:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Schema 'DB' does not exist

// stack trace
/ ...
```

#### Integration Test code

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ProviderTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(
                        TestObject.class,
                        TestService.class,
                        QueryValuesProviderImpl.class,
                        CriteriaQueryProviderFactory.class,
                        EntityManagerFactory.class
                        )
                .addClass(FlywayDataLoader.class)
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(new ByteArrayAsset(new byte[0]), ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
        System.out.println(jar.toString(true));
        return jar;
    }

    @Inject
    private TestService testService;

    @Test
    public void testGetTestResource() {
        List<TestObject> data = testService.getTestObjects(new QueryValues());

        assertNotNull(data);
        assertEquals(2, data.size());
    }
}
```

#### Flyway Java Script

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class FlywayDataLoader {

    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    public static void setup(
            @Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) final Object event
    ) {
        if (!initialized) {
            System.out.println("Loading Flyway Data");
            Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
            flyway.setDataSource(JDBC_URL, "sa", "");
            flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
            flyway.migrate();

            initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Flyway SQL script

This is split into two files (one for creating the Schema/Tables, the second for inserting the actual data). The files are in the `/resources/db.migration/` folder and are named `V1__CreateDatabase.sql` and `V2__AddTestClasses.sql` respectively.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA DB;

create table DB.TEST
(
    ID INT auto_increment
        constraint PK_REQUEST_AUDIT
            primary key,
    FN VARCHAR2(256 char) default NULL not null,
    LN VARCHAR2(256 char) default NULL not null,
    BD TIMESTAMP default SYSDATE not null
)
;

insert into DB.TEST (FN, LN, BD) VALUES ('Alice', 'Zyl', PARSEDATETIME('1985-03-13','yyyy-MM-dd','en'));
insert into DB.TEST (FN, LN, BD) VALUES ('Bart', 'Young', PARSEDATETIME('1988-03-25','yyyy-MM-dd','en'));
```

#### EntityManager

The `unitName` used here matches the Persistence Unit Name used in `persistence.xml`. The JDBC connection string used there is identical to the one used in the Flyway Java script.

```java
public class EntityManagerFactory {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="TestDS")
    private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    @Produces
    @Default
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager create() {
        return emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes @Default EntityManager em){
        if(em.isOpen()){
            em.close();
        }
    }

}
```

#### Persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestDS" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>myproject.beans.TestObject</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.ddl-auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

#### Unremarkable DAO class?

```java
@RequestScoped
public class TestService {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private CriteriaQueryProviderFactory criteriaQueryProviderFactory;

    public List<TestObject> getTestObjects(QueryValues queryValues) {
        CriteriaQueryProvider<TestObject> criteriaQueryProvider = criteriaQueryProviderFactory.getFactory();

        CriteriaQuery<TestObject> criteriaQuery = criteriaQueryProvider.buildModifiedQuery(queryValues, TestObject.class);
        TypedQuery<TestObject> typedQuery = criteriaQueryProvider.addSecondaryModifiers(criteriaQuery, queryValues, TestObject.class);

        TypedQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaQueryProvider.buildCountQuery(queryValues, TestObject.class);

        System.out.println(String.format("There are %d objects total!", countQuery.getSingleResult()));

        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way I found to integrate Flyway with Hibernate is to use an implementation of 
`org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator.html. That interface has two methods, `integrate` and `disintegrate`. If you put the code for running Flyway into the `integrate` method of your implementation everything should work fine. Hibernate loads implementations of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` the service loader mechanism from the Java Standard API, therefore you have to create a file `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` which contains the fully qualified class name of your implementation.

Best

Jens

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I made an `Integrator` class and got it to execute during startup, but the changes still don't persist in the database.